# how to interpret REL in agda

Tags: agda, dependent-type

I'm trying to understand some parts of the standard library of Agda, and I can't seem to figure out the definition of `REL`. 
FWIW here's the definition of `REL`:

```
-- Binary relations

-- Heterogeneous binary relations

REL : ∀ {a b} → Set a → Set b → (ℓ : Level) → Set (a ⊔ b ⊔ suc ℓ)
REL A B ℓ = A → B → Set ℓ
```

I can't find any documentation online explaining this, which is why I'm asking here. How does this define a binary relation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@RodrigoRibeiro's answer explains the `Level` bits, but once you get rid of universe levels, what does the type `Set → Set → Set` have to do with binary relations?

Suppose you have a binary relation `R ⊆ A × B`. The propositional way of modeling it is to create some indexed type `R : A → B → Set` such that for any `a : A, b : B`, `R a b` has inhabitants iff `(a, b) ∈ R`. So if you want to talk about all relations over `A` and `B`, you have to talk about all `A`- and `B`- indexed types, i.e. you have to talk about `RelationOverAandB = A → B → Set`.

If you then want to abstract over the relation's left- and right-hand base type, that means the choice of `A` and `B` are not fixed anymore. So you have to talk about `REL`, such that `REL A B = A → B → Set`.

What, then, is the type of `REL`? As we have seen from the `REL A B` example, it takes the choice of `A` and `B` as two arguments; and its result is the *type* `A → B → Set`.

So to summarize: given

```
A : Set
B : Set
```

we have

```
REL A B = A → B → Set
```

which itself has type `Set` (remember, we're ignoring universe levels here).

And thus,

```
REL : Set → Set → Set ∎
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess it's easier to look at an example:

```
import Level
open import Relation.Binary
open import Data.Nat.Base hiding (_≤_)

data _≤_ : REL ℕ ℕ Level.zero where
  z≤n : ∀ {n} -> 0 ≤ n
  s≤s : ∀ {n m} -> n ≤ m -> suc n ≤ suc m
```

The type signature is equivalent to

```
data _≤_ : ℕ -> ℕ -> Set where
```

So `_≤_` is a relation between two natural numbers. It contains all pairs of numbers such that the first number is less or equal than the second. In the same way we can write

```
open import Data.List.Base

data _∈_ {α} {A : Set α} : REL A (List A) Level.zero where
  here  : ∀ {x xs} -> x ∈ x ∷ xs
  there : ∀ {x y xs} -> x ∈ xs -> x ∈ y ∷ xs
```

The type signature is equivalent to

```
data _∈_ {α} {A : Set α} : A -> List A -> Set where
```

`_∈_` is a relation between elements of type `A` and lists of elements of type `A`.

The universe monomorphic variant of `REL` is itself a binary relation:

```
MonoREL : REL Set Set (Level.suc Level.zero)
MonoREL A B = A → B → Set
```

Answer (score 4):

To define a binary relation we need two sets, so `REL` needs, at least, two types. The type of `REL`:

```
REL : ∀ {a b} → Set a → Set b → (ℓ : Level) → Set (a ⊔ b ⊔ suc ℓ)
```

This type is a bit polluted due to universe level stuff. If you allow yourself a bit of informality, you can disable universe levels (more information about this [here](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.Pragmas)) and write `REL` as:

```
REL : Set -> Set -> Set
```

which is a type that expects two types as parameters.

The use of universes in type theory is to avoid paradoxes like [Russell's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) of set theory.

I'm not a type theory expert, but the interpretation of `REL` type can be summarised as:

- `Set a` and `Set b` are parameters types of universe levels `a` and`b`, respectively.
- The operator `⊔` returns the maximum of two parameter levels.

Hope that this can help you.