# Undersand Unary Relations and Universe polymorphism

Tags: agda

Background: I have some basic understanding of Agda and I'm trying to understand
the gist here:

https://gist.github.com/copumpkin/5945905

But I'm having problems understanding all the `Pred` stuff and the use of
universes.

This is the definition of Pred:

```
Pred : ∀ {a} → Set a → (ℓ : Level) → Set (a ⊔ suc ℓ)
Pred A ℓ = A → Set ℓ

-- Unary relations can be seen as sets
```

Why would I ever want such a type and what does that comment mean? It's being
used everywhere so I can't really proceed without understanding.

Following that, there's the record definition for a topological space:

```
record Space x ℓ : Set (Level.suc x ⊔ Level.suc ℓ)  where
```

What is this magic? I kind of understand that x is the level of our "points",
but what is `ℓ` and the resultant type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602204/how-to-interpret-rel-in-agda) about binary relations.

Under the [Curry–Howard interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) each `A` of type `Set` (or `Set ℓ` in a universe polymorphic setting) is a proposition. Thus `P` of type `A -> Set` for some `A` is a predicate defined on elements of `A`.

Consider e.g. a predicate `Positive` which holds only for natural numbers of the form `suc n` for some `n` (I'm out of my machine hence the ASCII):

```
data Positive : Nat -> Set where
  positive : forall n -> Positive (suc n)
```

`positive n` is a (or, rather, the) proof of `Positive (suc n)`. Having `Pred A = A -> Set` we can write the type signature of `Positive` as

```
data Positive : Pred Nat where
```

Another example is `All` from the `Data.List.All` module in the standard library. It's defined as

```
data All {a p} {A : Set a}
         (P : A → Set p) : List A → Set (p ⊔ a) where
  []  : All P []
  _∷_ : ∀ {x xs} (px : P x) (pxs : All P xs) → All P (x ∷ xs)
```

`All P` is a predicate that holds for any list `xs` whenever `P` holds for each element of the list. Using the universe polymorphic definition of `Pred` we can write the type signature of `All` as

```
data All {a p} {A : Set a}
         (P : Pred A p) : Pred (List A) (p ⊔ a) where
```

(and make it clear that `All` is a predicate transformer). So `Pred` is mostly notational convenience.

As to universe polymorphism there are some [docs](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/%E2%80%8E?n=ReferenceManual.UniversePolymorphism) in the old Agda wiki. In your example `x` is the level of the universe where the type of points (`X`) lies. That `ℓ` is used in `Pred (Pred X ℓ) ℓ` — the type of predicates defined on predicates defined on elements of `X` (I can't comment on the topological meaning of this expression). `Set x` lies in `Set (suc x)` and `Pred (Pred X ℓ) ℓ` (which unfolds into `(X -> Set ℓ) -> Set ℓ`) lies in `Set (suc ℓ)` hence the whole `Space x ℓ` lies in `Set (suc x ⊔ suc ℓ)`.

Comment: That clarifies a bunch. I assume that `Pred (x l)` is a subset of `X` then. While `Pred (Pred x l)` is the characteristic function for open sets.

Comment: @rgrinberg, `Pred X ℓ` is a subset of `X`, yes.